# How to implement this SQL using CriteriaBuilder to build a Predicate?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteriaquery

Im using `Specification`s that use `CriteriaBuilder` to filter data which is called from my `JpaRepository` using `findAll()`, but now I have a more complicated query in SQL that I need to generate a `Predicate` in my specification.

The SQL query is:

```
SELECT a.*
    FROM A a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT e.a_id, sum(e.amount) AS matched_total
    FROM E e
GROUP BY e.a_id
HAVING e.a_id IS NOT NULL) AS sub ON sub.a_id = a.id
WHERE coalesce(matched_total, 0) = a.amount;
```

Entity E links to A:

```
+--------+
| id     |
| amount |
| a_id   |
+--------+
```

Entity A:

```
+--------+
| id     |
| amount |
+--------+
```

(Or maybe there is a way to write this as HQL and use that to build a `Predicate` somehow ?)

Additional notes:

1. There is a one-to-many relationship between E and A, so several rows in A could be associated to a single row in E.
2. The `a_id` in E is also nullable, so potentially there could be rows in A not associated with a row in E - we need to ignore those.
3. Ultimately we want to find all the rows in A that are associated to a single row in E but only where the `amount`s of the rows in A sum up to the single `amount` row in E - this is why we calculate `matched_total`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, isn't the query equivalent to the following?

```
SELECT *
FROM A a
WHERE a.amount > (
    SELECT SUM(e.amount)
    FROM E e
    WHERE e.a_id = a.id
)
```

The above query is easily translatable to Criteria API, sth along the lines of:

```
Root<A> a = cq.from(A.class);
Subquery<Integer> sum = cq.subquery(Integer.class);
Root<E> e = sum.from(E.class);
sum.select(cb.sum(e.get(E_.amount));
sum.where(cb.equal(e.join(E_.a), a);

cq.where(cb.greaterThan(a.get(A_.amount), sum);
```

Comment: I added some notes above because I realized there's some missing crucial information. Also note I have changed the original query to `=` in the final `WHERE` clause. We want to ignore rows that don't add up to `matched_total`s.

Comment: I still fail to see the difference. Of course the rows in E whose `a_id` is null are not included - that's what the `WHERE e.a_id = a.id` clause is for. Could you perhaps provide an example where you think the queries return different results? (assuming `>` is replaced with `=`)

Comment: Sorry in the delay in getting back to this - I have been off for a few days and have not been able to test this. Is there a way to do this without using the Metamodel API?